# Google Sheet creating an IF or IFS

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to auto populate information based on what I am inputting into one column to another.

For example: Column D has a list I choose from:  CD, DD, CC, Closed.  Based on what is input in Column D in each row I am looking to populate that information in each individual rows for column N though P.

D2=Closed,  N though P should state NA.

D3=CD or DD or CC.  N though P is left blank.

When I try IFS function it will state the NA if D is Closed but for CD, DD or CC it will spilt out False.  How do I leave the N-P columns blank if D3 or other D columns are not equal to Closed?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="Closed", {"NA","NA","NA","NA"}, ))
```